# How to pronounce Corps' with the apostrophe

Tags: pronunciation

I came across the phrase "Apple Corps’ London office". I know I should pronounce corps the same as "core", but how should I do it with the s'?

The whole sentence is:

> But Jackson was stunned by what he saw that first week, watching it from morning till night at Apple Corps’ London office and being brought a daily Big Mac.

Extracted from *The Guardian* article: [I just can’t believe it exists](https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2021/nov/20/i-just-cant-believe-it-exists-peter-jackson-takes-us-into-the-beatles-vault-locked-up-for-52-years).

Comment: The quoted example strikes me as a headline-style abbreviation for "corporations." I have trouble envisioning a usage in which the actual word "corps" would be appropriate. I would also expect that, if the apostrophe was intended to indicate abbreviation, it would be better placed between the "p" and "s." And such abbreviations aren't very concerned with pronunciation, but presumably in such a case the "p" would be voiced.

Comment: "Corps" is only pronounced like "core" when it has the meaning of a military unit or analogous group. For example, "marine corps" is pronounced like "marine core". In this case, it's clearly an abbreviation of "corporation" (per Andy Bonner), so it would not have that special pronunciation.

Comment: @siride clearly The Beatles' company [Apple Corps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Corps) was never intended to be pronounced 'corpse' but 'core'.

Comment: Sorry, the whole sentence is:
"But Jackson was stunned by what he saw that first week, watching it from morning till night at Apple Corps’ London office and being brought a daily Big Mac."
Extracted from The Guardian's article:
https://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2021/nov/20/i-just-cant-believe-it-exists-peter-jackson-takes-us-into-the-beatles-vault-locked-up-for-52-years

Comment: @WeatherVane Oops! I thought they were talking about Apple, the computer company.

Comment: So, Corps’ should be pronounced as "korz" with the apostrophe, then?

Comment: In this context, yes. The pun was 'Apple Corps' – 'apple core' so IMO the possessive should follow on, and not revert to another pronunciation.

Comment: That clarifies it! Thank you, @WeatherVane ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The English word "corps" (meaning a body of troops or other organization) is pronounced like "core" with a silent P and S. That's the joke - the company, which produced the Beatles albums, was called "Apple Corps" which sounds like "apple core". (It's not to be confused with Apple Corp, that makes Macintosh computers.)

The possessive of words ending in S is formed by adding an apostrophe at the end of the word. Usually in these cases the possessive is pronounced exactly the same as the main word (i.e. the "Jones" in "Mr. Jones' wife goes out." is pronounced exactly the same as in "Mr. Jones goes out.")

However with the special and unusual case of a silent S **it is usual to pronounce the S in the possessive.** This is because we are used to having an S on the possessive.

So

> "Apple Corps has an office in London" - pronounced "core"

> "Apple Corps' London office" - pronounced "cores"

(It's also arguable that "corps's" is an allowed written possessive, pronounced the same.)

See [Chicago Manual of Style](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/SecondThoughts.html).

Comment: I agree, but supporting references needed.

Answer (score 2):

OED

> corps, n.1
>
> Pronunciation: Brit./kɔː/, U.S. /kɔr/
>
> Etymology: As short for corps d'armée.
>
> 2. Military.  a. A division of an army, forming a tactical unit; a body of troops regularly organized; a body of men who are assigned to a special service.
> 3. general.  a. A body or company of persons associated in a common organization, or acting under a common direction.

Apple Corps' Office = **/ˈapl kɔːz ˈɒfɪs/**

Answer (score -4):

The letter 'S' is pronounced, with a silent letter 'P.'